# Copy paste data based on value (1, 2, or 3) in column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have Sheet1 which contains multiple columns of data. My macro is supposed to grab specific columns from Sheet1, open up Sheet2, and then paste the data into Sheet2 using other logic.

In column A, I have item numbers that range from 1-4, which have the corresponding Item Name in Column B. The top level item will always be 1 (whole product), but depending on the what creates the final product, it can have multiple item number 2, 3, and 4 which are nested underneath each other. For visual purposes:

`1 Phone
   2 Battery
     3 Lithium
     3 LithiumX
   2 Camera
     3 Glass
       4 Bulb
       4 Lens`

Of course in excel, all the numbers will be aligned in column A and the names will aligned in column B. I'm trying to create a VBA code/logic that when the item number is 1, we copy that item name into column B of the new sheet. If item number is 2, we copy that item name into column C of the new sheet, so on and so forth for 3 and 4. The only tricky part is that if the Item name is different for item numbers 2, 3 or 4, the logic needs to catch that copy/paste the correct names. So my end data would look something like this.

`|A|  B  |    C    |    D    |     E    |
 |1|Phone|         |         |
 |2|Phone| Battery |         |
 |4|Phone| Battery | Lithium |
 |5|Phone| Battery | LithiumX|
 |6|Phone| Battery | LithiumX|
 |7|Phone| Camera  |         |
 |8|Phone| Camera  | Glass   |
 |9|Phone| Camera  | Glass   |  Bulb    |`

My Current VBA Code is below, which doesn't do much but copy and paste the data from sheet1 to sheet2:

`

```
cls = Array("A1", "B1")

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
'Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set sh2 = Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, After:=Application.ActiveSheet)
On Error Resume Next
sh2.Name = "Test"
On Error GoTo 0

'Clear sheet 2
sh2.Cells.Clear

'cut specific headers from Sheet 1 and paste to sheet 2
With sh2
    LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For n = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
        Me.Range(cls(n)).Copy Destination:=.Cells(LR, n + 1)
    Next n
End With

Let lrow1 = sh1.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrow1
    Let lrow3 = sh2.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row
        sh2.Cells(lrow3 + 1, 1) = sh1.Cells(i, 1)
        sh2.Cells(lrow3 + 1, 2) = sh1.Cells(i, 2)

Next i
```

`
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You say you want to copy data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`. You provide code and say it "doesn't do much but copy and paste the data from sheet1 to sheet2". That sounds like it does what you want. Could you be more specific about where the issue is?

Comment: Of course. Right now it just mirrors the data from `sheet1` to `sheet2`. But my end goal is for my data to copy/paste based off the parent/child relationship based on Item number. If we have item1 in `sheet1`, then in row 2, cell 2 of `sheet2` should be `|Phone|`. In row 3, cell 2 of `sheet2` because it has a parent item of 1 and it is a child item of 2, it should be `|Phone|Battery|`.

Comment: So are you looking for something thats like
`1| 1 2 |1 2 3(1)|1 2 3 (2)|` etc etc?

Comment: More like row1 should have `Item1 name (Phone)`. Then in row2, it should have `Item1 name (Phone)` in one cell and then `Item2 name(Battery)` in the cell to the right in `sheet2`

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I've done here is used a loop to check through every entry in the A column and used some `if/elseif` statements to determine what values need to be updated. So long as the data is always as you have formatted above I believe this should work.

It updates the appropriate slot of data as it progresses down the list of levels, but upon hitting a number, it'll set every level that comes after it to be `NULL`. I used `NULL` because it prints the same as a "" in excel, but it uses less memory.

I've tried to speed it up a bit by doing most of the comparison in memory by taking all the data at once and using arrays. It should be noted, however, you could also make it so that you only perform the print operation once by using a second variant array that you re-dimension as you go, but I've chosen not to here. If there are a large number of items, it is worth considering as continuously accessing the sheet will severely slow down your program.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CascadingList()
    Dim Levels(1 To 4) As String
    Dim Subcount As Long
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Data() As Variant

    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Data = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & Lastrow).Value
    Subcount = 1

    For cell = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(cell, 1) = 1 Then
            Levels(1) = Data(cell, 2)
            Levels(2) = vbNullString
            Levels(3) = vbNullString
            Levels(4) = vbNullString
        ElseIf Data(cell, 1) = 2 Then
            Levels(2) = Data(cell, 2)
            Levels(3) = vbNullString
            Levels(4) = vbNullString
        ElseIf Data(cell, 1) = 3 Then
            Levels(3) = Data(cell, 2)
            Levels(4) = vbNullString
        ElseIf Data(cell, 1) = 4 Then
            Levels(4) = Data(cell, 2)
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & Subcount & ":D" & Subcount).Value = Levels
        Subcount = Subcount + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

To clarify, this will start looking at the levels from `A1` downwards and will paste values into `A1:D1` of the second sheet downwards. Please alter the ranges so that it works with your code.

Comment: This code worked flawlessly. Thank you for the fast response and answer!